# pgfplots: Same exponent for all tick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having trouble getting pgfplots to display the same exponent for all y tick labels. Currently, my y axis looks like this:

[image]

However, I would like to have the same exponent for every y tick, so `0.5*10^5` and `0*10^5` (or just `0` without an exponent).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=200000,
            scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/sci},
        ]
    
        \addplot coordinates {(0, 0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Check out `scaled ticks` in the manual (currently around page 350). Another method that is guaranteed to work is to down-scale all numbers by 1e4, and add that back when typesetting labels.

Comment: In case you don't like the scaling on top of the axis there are *plenty* of ways to achieve something similar. But each way has a preferred use case, so I don't want to create all of them here. If you would add a concrete use case for your question, I'll be happy to add another answer how I would make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `relative*` option of the `\pgfmathprintnumber` command provided by **pgfplotstable** package (and used by pgfplots). According to the documentation, *This options  Configures \pgfmathprintnumber to format numbers relative to an order of magnitude, 10^r, where r is an integer number.*

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=200000,
            scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel style={
              /pgf/number format/relative*=5,
            },
        ]
    
        \addplot coordinates {(0, 0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the 50,000 number is not satisfactory, you can provide the command that parse and format the number with command `yticklabel`. For example, you can use the command `\num` from **siunitx** package, that has many option for formatting the number:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=200000,
            scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel={
              \num[
                round-mode=figures,
                scientific-notation=fixed,
                fixed-exponent=5
              ]{\tick}
            },
        ]
    
        \addplot coordinates {(0, 0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Process the 0 ticklabel.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=200000,
            scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel={
              \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tickint\tick
              \ifnum\tickint=0
                \num{0.0e5}
              \else
                \num[
                  round-mode=figures,
                  scientific-notation=fixed,
                  fixed-exponent=5
                ]{\tick}
              \fi
            },
        ]
    
        \addplot coordinates {(0, 0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you could use `\dim\tick pt=0pt` instead of `\ifnum` if the y-axis had lower values, but for this case this solution would give the error `dim too large`.

Comment: OP seems to be no longer available anymore. I basically think he had your last solution in mind. There are only 2 minor problems: The extra 0 in `0.50x10^5` and the dot in `0.`. You know how to fix that. +1

Comment: I have a solution for the 0.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I did not thought that such an easy looking axis describtion will be so tedious to make. If you ever find out how to get rid of the extra 0 in 0.50 you are welcome. I will award this answer the bounty.

Comment: @Roland, this can easily be done by changing `round-mode=figures` to `round-mode=places` and adding `round-precision=1`.

Comment: @Roland Sorry for not being active over the last few days, there was a lot to do in university. The solution by Sergio and the additions is indeed what I was looking for <3

Answer (score 3):

Best I could do (so far):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{fixed zerofill,precision=1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymin=0,
            ymax=200000,
            xmin=-0.1,
            xmax=4.1,
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=0},
            scaled ticks=true,
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/precision=1
            },
        ]   
        \addplot coordinates {(3, 50000)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are asking for is the **default** behavior of PGFPlots. So you get -- besides the "zerofill" -- exactly the same result with the following code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,
        ymax=200000,
        xmin=-0.1,
        xmax=4.1,
%        yticklabel style={
%            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
%            /pgf/number format/precision=1,
%        },
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(3, 50000)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]